# Joining two datasets in different locations in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

My team has datasets in the EU and US. I want to join two tables, one from a dataset in EU and one from the US. When I try to do this I get an error saying that the table from the other location could not be located. I tried to copy the table as well (which would not be a long term solution, since I need to collect ongoing metrics), but that didn't work.

What is the proper way to join and analyze datasets in different locations?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy datasets between regions using BigQuery `Data Transfer Service`. Here is the documentation link [Copying Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#bq)

BigQuery command-line option to copy dataset from EU region to US region:

```
bq mk --transfer_config \
      --project_id=data-lab \
      --data_source=cross_region_copy \
      --target_dataset=bq_poc_us \
      --display_name='Dataset Copy' \
      --params='{"source_dataset_id":"bq_poc_eu","source_project_id":"data-lab"}'
```